# Selecting from a table based on value in a foreign table rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have two models, `Admin` and `Role`. An admin belongs_to a role, and has a `role_id` field. `Role` has a field `name`. How do I write an ActiveRecord query where I select all `Admin`s with a `role.name` of `Manager`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just:

```
Admin.joins(:role).merge(Role.where(name: 'Manager'))
```

Or if you had defined a relation: Role has_many :admins

```
Role.find_by(name: 'Manager').admins
```